# NuGet Package Questions (Asked by a NuGet *Newbie*)

Tags: nuget-package

I have a couple of NuGet package questions that I cannot seem to locate an answer for.

First, most packages have one or more dependencies on other packages.  These dependencies are listed with a minimum (and sometimes, maximum) version number.  What is an *easy* way to determine this range when creating packages?  For example, my code depends on a particular package.  If I install the earliest version, my code will not compile.  If I install the latest version, my code will compile.  Somewhere along the line (between the oldest and newest version), the code I need to reference was added.  How do I determine where (read, what version) this was added in a particular package so I can set the minimum version?

Second, when I set a package dependency, is it an *all or nothing* type of thing?  By that, I might need only an assembly or two from a package but not the rest.  Is there any way to get rid of the extra *stuff*?  As an example, the package I use has an indirect dependency on Newtownsoft.Json.  However, my code does not use this assembly in any way.  Should I just ignore this?  I don't want extra assemblies that are not required floating around.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, package dependency supposed to be essential for the dll to compile, so its strange that some of the dll`s are unnecessary. But if indeed its the case, there is no way to avoid it, in the package install process, because the NuGet recognize all the dll files under the lib folder in the nuget package, and add them as reference. 
But you can delete the reference from the project config file (.csproj), and in the package restore process, nuget only download and extract the nuget package. and don`t touch the .csproj files.

I didn`t understand exactly your first question, but you can enforce the nuget package version specific for your needs, link: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning